# Twig for CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, twig

I am trying to use Twig with CakePHP, so I installed this plugin:
https://github.com/predominant/TwigView

And in CakePHP's demo, we build a blog, and I can use this in a tpl file:

```
{% for post in posts %}
<tr>
    <td>{{post.Post.id}}</td>
    <td>{{post.Post.title}}</td>
    <td>Edit | Delete</td>
    <td>{{post.Post.created|date("F j, Y")}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

What I can't get to work, is converting this:

```
<?php
echo $this->Html->link(
    'Add Post', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action'     => 'add')
);
?>
```

I have tried all of these, and none of them work:

```
{{ html.link("Add Post", {"controller" : "posts", "action" : "add"}) }}
{{ _view.html.link("Add Post", {"controller" : "posts", "action" : "add"}) }}
{{ this.html.link("Add Post", {"controller" : "posts", "action" : "add"}) }}
```

I don't get any errors, it just gets replaced with nothing. Anyone know how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly declare the helpers in the controller to make it work:

```
public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
```

See GitHub issue [#14](https://github.com/predominant/TwigView/issues/14) and [#13](https://github.com/predominant/TwigView/issues/13) where I got this from.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it just won't take an array as the argument or doesn't understand what controller or action is. Try:

```
{{ html.link("Add Post", "/posts/add" }}
```

Comment: Nope, there was no difference

Answer (score 0):

Is it escaping the output? If so, to get the full HTML, use RAW

```
{{ html.link("Add Post", {"controller" : "posts", "action" : "add"})|raw }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Proper syntax for hyperlinks html helper is:

```
{{ html.link('Add Post', '/posts/add') }}
```