# CakePHP TwigView does not render Correctly

Tags: php, html, cakephp, twig, cakephp-2.4

Thanks to [burzum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171209/burzum) for helping configure TwigView with CakePHP.

I was able to use .tpl extention with CakePHP.

However, not everything renders perfect. My default.tpl layout file is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    {{ html.charset() }}
    <title>{{ 'CakePHP: the rapid development php framework'|trans }}: {{ title_for_layout }}</title>
    {{ html.meta('icon') }}
    {{ html.css('cake.generic') }}
    {{ scripts_for_layout }}
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <h1>{{ 
                html.link('CakePHP: the rapid development php framework'|trans, 'http://cakephp.org')
            }}</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            {{ session.flash() }}{{ session.flash('auth') }}
            {{ content_for_layout }}
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
        {{ 
            html.image('cake.power.gif', {
                'alt': 'Powered by CakePHP'|trans,
                'url': 'http://cakephp.org'
            })
        }}
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, it renders below

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>CakePHP: the rapid development php framework: Testing</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <h1></h1>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div class"alert alert-info>Hello There!</div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Helpers does not render. Please Help!

The link to my previous post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138038/cakephp-twigview-plugin-missing-view-error)

I am using [predominant cakephp plugin](https://github.com/predominant/TwigView).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/757218/alex) the issue is resolved.

I got the answer from another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18309865/1794539).

We have the explicitly declare the helpers in the controller to make it work:

```
public $helpers = array('Html');
```